# Android webView blinks

Tags: android, webview

The webview in my app (where i present some RSS news) uses to blink when i scroll,or sometimes if i read the article.
How can i fix it?

the problem is the same in my 4.1.1 device and in the emulator.
this is my webview:

```
final WebView desc = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        desc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                desc.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                        + "document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.display = 'none'; "
                        + "})()");
            }
        });



        // Set webview properties
        WebSettings ws = desc.getSettings();

        ws.setSupportZoom(true);
        // ws.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        ws.setLightTouchEnabled(false);
        ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.766.0 Safari/534.36");

        // ws.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
        // desc.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        desc.loadDataWithBaseURL("", DESC,
                "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

put android:hardwareAccelerated="false" to that activity.

I hope it may helps

Thanks,
Chaitanya.K

Answer (score 0):

when you set android:hardwareAccelerated="false" to that activity,you'd better not use animation in that activity.otherwise animation will be so bad.
you could set webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
it also close hardwareAccelerated